# How can I add a link to the main menu from a custom module?

Tags: navigation

I've seen numerous questions on how to address this, but I've not quite found the answer. I'd like to add an additional link to the `main` menu. I've attempted this in `my_module.links.menu.yml` and run `drush cr`. This doesn't seem to limited impact.

This item will show up under the Tools menu, but not main.

```
my_module.list:
  title: 'List All Computers'
  description: 'Show all known computers'
  route_name: my_module.listAllComputers
  parent: main
```

Is there something wrong with the above? Is PHP a better way to add a link to the main menu? If so, where? Do I use a Drupal 8 hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the key `menu_name` that will permit the addition of your new menu item into your main menu.

```
my_module.list:
  title: 'List All Computers'
  description: 'Show all known computers'
  route_name: my_module.listAllComputers
  parent: main
  menu_name: main
```

The `parent` key is not mandatory, so if you want your link to be shown on the first level of your main_menu, you don't need it.